# Code Igniter installation - can't find error

Tags: codeigniter, installation, xampp

I have followed the instructions to install Code Igniter
http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/installation/index.html

Now I have a page that says An error has encountered, _error_ctrl.

I did not find any error in appache or php error log.

Since I am new to Code Igniter and have no idea where to look for it now.

I am using Xampp server.

Comment: My own opinion better to learn with codeigniter 2.2.1 http://www.codeigniter.com/ which is stable version then once got to know more and and then use CI3. it is not completed as yet still bugs to work out.

Comment: what OS are you using?

Comment: i am using windows 8

Comment: are you using any IDE?

Comment: did you setup any encryption keys in your config file?

Comment: did you set up your database in database.php?

Comment: CodeIgniter doesn't take any configuration. Just copy the files to your web server and you should be able to see the welcome message straight away. Have you seen this?

Comment: it turns out I do not get the error when I use https.

Comment: I still do not know why..

Comment: have you tried installing it from scratch again? just leave all the default settings as is

Comment: try codeigniter 2.2.1 -- version 3 is beta.

Comment: I have tried 2.2.1, I ran into the same issue